# The value of $f'(\sqrt{\pi})+g'(\sqrt{\pi}).$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f(x)=(\int_{0}^{x}e^{-t^{2}}dt)^{2}$ and $g(x)=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{e^{-x^{2(1+t^{2})}}}{1+t^{2}}dt.$ Then what is the value of $f'(\sqrt{\pi})+g'(\sqrt{\pi})?$ According to me $g'(\sqrt{\pi})$ is equal to zero. But i dont't know how to find $f'(\sqrt{\pi})$. I am thinking it by fundamental theorem of calculus. Please suggest me to find its value. Thanks.

Comment: $g'(\sqrt{π})$ doesn't seem to be $0$.

Comment: I am saying it as it is proper integral....

Comment: $$f'(x) + g'(x) = 0 \quad \quad \text{ for all } x\in \mathbb{R}$$ this problem is in fact another famous way to evaluate the Gaussian integral.

Comment: @neelkanth $g'(x) = \int_0^1 \frac{\exp(-x^2 (1 + t^2))}{1 + t^2} \cdot (-2x(1 + t^2)) \,\mathrm{d} t = -2x \int_0^1 \exp(-x^2 (1 + t^2)) \,\mathrm{d} t$.

Comment: How $f'+g'=0?...........$

Comment: @neelkanth See my comment below my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I dont't know how to find $f'(\sqrt{\pi}).$*

By applying the chain rule to
$$
f(x)=\left(\int_{0}^{x}e^{-t^{2}}dt\right)^{2}
$$ one gets
$$
f'(x)=2e^{-x^{2}}\int_{0}^{x}e^{-t^{2}}dt
$$ putting $x=\sqrt{\pi}$ gives a result in terms of the [error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function).

Comment: is it complete derivative?

Comment: Yes you applied fundamental theorem...

Comment: Am i right that $g'(\sqrt{\pi})=0$

Comment: Yes, we use that $\frac{d}{dx}\left(\int_{0}^{x}e^{-t^{2}}dt\right)=e^{-x^{2}}$.

Comment: We have $$g'(x)=-2x\int_{0}^{1}e^{-x^2{(1+t^{2})}}dt$$ which only vanishes at $x=0$.

Comment: Since by the change of variable $u=xt$, $du=xdt$, $$g'(x)=-2x\int_{0}^{1}e^{-x^2{(1+t^{2})}}dt=-2e^{-x^{2}}\int_{0}^{x}e^{-u^{2}}du=-f(x)$$ one then gets $$f'(x)+g'(x)=0.$$

Comment: I meant above $g'(x)=\cdots = -f'(x)$